# Sitecore workbox "empty string is not allowed" error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-workflow

Encountering this exception when trying to make a user created workflow visible within workbox.

```
Empty string is not allowed.
Parameter name: value.
Actual value was .
```

Trace as follows.

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Empty string is not allowed.
Parameter name: value.
Actual value was .]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.AssertString(String argument, String name, Boolean allowEmpty) +136
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.CommandBuilders.CommandBuilder.Add(String key, String value) +42
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm.CreateCommand(IWorkflow workflow, WorkflowCommand command, Item item, XmlControl workboxItem) +280
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm.CreateItem(IWorkflow workflow, Item item, Control control) +1758
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm.DisplayState(IWorkflow workflow, WorkflowState state, DataUri[] items, Control control, Int32 offset, Int32 pageSize) +167
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm.DisplayStates(IWorkflow workflow, XmlControl placeholder) +654
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm.DisplayWorkflow(IWorkflow workflow) +439
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm.Pane_Toggle(String id) +141
```

At first I thought it was the fact that some items within the workflow had no state values set so I corrected it and the problem persists.

Sitecore version is 7.0 (rev. 130918)

There's nothing particularly special about this workflow, just the standard three states with email alerts and auto-publishing. I believe it was just a direct duplication of the standard workflow with new names.

I've come late into this project after it has gone into production so I may still discover something odd about the setup.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is to the `CreateItem` step of the process. Essentially it is trying to create a new Item but run rules against the naming of the Item.

"Actual value was ." Actually refers to the regular expressions run against the proposed Item name being an empty string, not a full stop.

The resolution is to confirm the following settings in the web.config have these (or something similar) values and if not add the values.

```xml
<setting name="InvalidItemNameChars" value="\/:?&quot;&lt;>|[]" />

<setting name="ItemNameValidation" value="^[\w\*\$][\w\s\-\$]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$" />
```

Often they are removed to upload packages with Items containing these characters but the step to undo the change is forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

See the code of the CreateCommand class:

```cs
private void CreateCommand(IWorkflow workflow, WorkflowCommand command, Item item, XmlControl workboxItem)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(workflow, "workflow");
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(command, "command");
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(workboxItem, "workboxItem");
    XmlControl webControl = Resource.GetWebControl("WorkboxCommand") as XmlControl;
    Assert.IsNotNull(webControl, "workboxCommand is null");
    webControl["Header"] = command.DisplayName;
    webControl["Icon"] = command.Icon;
    CommandBuilder builder = new CommandBuilder("workflow:send");
    builder.Add("id", item.ID.ToString());
    builder.Add("la", item.Language.Name);
    builder.Add("vs", item.Version.ToString());
    builder.Add("command", command.CommandID);
    builder.Add("wf", workflow.WorkflowID);
    builder.Add("ui", command.HasUI);
    builder.Add("suppresscomment", command.SuppressComment);
    webControl["Command"] = builder.ToString();
    workboxItem.AddControl(webControl);
}
```

One of the values that is added to the `builder.Add()` line is empty. Seems like there is some misconfiguration in your workflow Commands.

Hope this helps to put you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer really: I'm working on the same project as @wardey, and this may help indicate what the issue is?
The Workbox empty string is not allowed error only appears to happen when they user is set to be an administrator.
I take the "user is administrator" setting off and I can see the Workflow.